# Additive gaussian process regression with interaction

Tags: process, gaussian

I'm wondering if there's a good R package that will fit a regression model of the form y=f(z) + g(x)t, where z are baseline variables, x are variables that may impact treatment effectiveness, t is a treatment indicator, and f(z), g(x) are separate gaussian processes. Most packages seem to fit models of the form y=g(x).

I've looked at GauPro, mlegp, and brms but I wasn't able to figure out how to use these to fit this type of model.

Thanks!